# How to create a list with the characters of a string?

Tags: python, string, list

Is it possible to transform a string into a list, like this:

```
"5+6"
```

into

```
["5", "+", "6"]
```

Comment: Do you simply want to turn single characters into a list, or do you want to tokenize the input, i.e. turn `57+23` into `["57", "+", "23"]`?

Answer (score 21):

```
list('5+6')
```

returns

```
['5', '+', '6']
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, very simply:

```
>>> s = "5+6"
>>> list(s)
['5', '+', '6']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using map inbuilt list creation to work

Code:

```
map(None,"sart")
```

**Output:**

```
['s', 'a', 'r', 't']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list comprehension like:

```
lst = [x for x in "5+6"]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

in python 3
you could make this ...

```
>>> s = 'bioinform'
>>> s
'bioinform'
>>> w = list(s)
>>> w
['b', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'n', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm']
>>>
```

but if you give list any value will give you an error so you should restart your IDLE