# How do I convert string characters into a list?

Tags: python, string, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a list with the characters of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501641/how-to-create-a-list-with-the-characters-of-a-string)

Example:

```
'abc'
```

becomes

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Is it a combination of split and slicing?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to create a list with the characters of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5501641/1142167)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
>>> x = 'abc'
>>> list(x)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can access individual characters from a string itself:

```
>>> x = 'abc'
>>> x[1]
'b'
```

Comment: Wow. I tried a bunch of elaborate techniques and it was just one command. Thank you so much. Saved me from a headache.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to iterate over the string you do not even need to convert it to a list:

```
>>> n = 'abc'
>>> for i in n:
...     print i
... 
a
b
c
```

or

```
>>> n[1]
'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourstring = 'abc'
[char for char in yourstring]
```

Comment: While that _does_ work, it's unnecessarily complex for a simple task. As Paolo wrote, use `list(yourstring)`.

Comment: I like this one because it uses the intrinsic grammar of the language and not a specialized tool.