# Split words in string into nested lists of characters

Tags: python, string, list, split

Can anyone help me with a list comprehension to split a string into a nested list of words and characters? i.e:

```
mystring = "this is a string"
```

Wanted ouput:

```
[['t','h','i','s'],['i','s'],['a'],['s','t','r','i','n','g']]
```

I've tried the following, but it doesnt split 'x' into nested list:

```
mylist = [x.split() for x in mystring.split(' ')]
print(mylist)
[['this'],['is'],['a'],['string']]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert string characters into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610158/how-do-i-convert-string-characters-into-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[list(x) for x in mystring.split(' ')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
[[j for j in i] for i in mystring.split()]
```

Yields:

```
[['t', 'h', 'i', 's'], ['i', 's'], ['a'], ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']]
```

Comment: Or just `list(map(list, mystring.split()))`.

Comment: That's also a perfectly good solution. I figured this was more readable to the OP, that's all.

Comment: Absolutely, your code is just as correct. My comment was meant to, you know, spark some admiration towards functional programming in people:)

Answer (score 1):

You need `list(x)` instead of `x.split()`:

```
[list(x) for x in mystring.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly similar to other answers

```
map(list,mystring.split(" "))
```