# How do you separate a column with words not separated at all. The data loaded from pd.read_table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

So I uploaded a data from pd.read_table:

```
df = pd.read_table('Test_Data.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('A', 'B'))
```

and the data is:

```
    A                                                   B
0   AAABBABAABBAAABBBBAABBBABAAABAAAAABBBABBBAAABB...   True
1   AABAABABBBABAAAAABAAABBAABAABBABABBAAABABBBBAB...   True
2   BAAABBBBABABABBBABBAAABAAAAAAABBBBAABABABBBAAB...   True
3   BAABBABBABBAAAABABBBAAAAAAAABAAABBAAAABBAABBAA...   True
4   ABBABBBABBAABAABABBAAABAAAAABABABAABBAABBBAABA...   True
```

Column A is 100 alphabets. I want to split each in separate columns. I want to have 100 columns of these alphabets and column B as it is. How must I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Related Question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848671/how-to-convert-strings-in-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-list-or-an-array-of-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# for example        
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["ABB"]*5, "B": [True]*5})
print(df)

     A     B
0  ABB  True
1  ABB  True
2  ABB  True
3  ABB  True
4  ABB  True

# split string
df["A"] = df["A"].apply(list)
print(df)

           A     B
0  [A, B, B]  True
1  [A, B, B]  True
2  [A, B, B]  True
3  [A, B, B]  True
4  [A, B, B]  True

# new columns' names, here is 3, you could set 100
col_names = list(range(3))
df = pd.concat([df['A'].apply(pd.Series, index=col_names), df["B"]], axis=1)
print(df)


   0  1  2     B
0  A  B  B  True
1  A  B  B  True
2  A  B  B  True
3  A  B  B  True
4  A  B  B  True
```

Comment: Thanks Geneva, it helps a lot!

Comment: If this answers your question, it would be kind to upvote the answer and click the checkmark to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I can't upvote it as i don't have 15 points but I am going to check mark it. It would be nice if you can upvote the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed width text to column converting option.

Data > Text to Column >

Excel will let you put pointer where you want the separation to applied.[image]