# Splitting Strings into a single character of having while the string is having spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am cleaning some data for my practice. The restriction is I am not using Pandas, so I am doing it with regular python.

My Dara contains a list of lists, consider this

> dataset = [["My name is Anas", 1.92],["I am data Scientist",1.88],["I am Studying BSCS",2.0]]

The float number on every list's first index ensures that the `dataset` has a list of lists with multiple values.

My code is

```
for i in dataset:
    for j in i:
       print(j[0].split())
```

the output is now `["My","Name","is","Anas"]` and same for all

I want my output should be look like this `["M","y","N","a","m","e","i","s","A","n","a","s"]`

or like this

```
 [['M', 'y', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'i', 's', 'A', 'n', 'a', 's'],[ 'I', 'a', 'm', 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', 'S', 'c', 'i', 'e', 'n', 't', 'i', 's', 't'], ['I', 'a', 'm', 'S', 't', 'u', 'd', 'y', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'S']]
```

How to optimize this code? please reply with your valuable answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a list with the characters of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501641/how-to-create-a-list-with-the-characters-of-a-string)

Comment: Would you like to make your mind up about what the output should be? I provided a perfectly reasonable answer based on your original requirements now you want something else.

Comment: "the output is now `["My","Name","is","Anas"]` and same for all" No it isn't; the output is `['M']` followed by a `TypeError`. "or like this" Well, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
k=[]
for i in dataset:
    for j in i[0]:
        if j!=' ':
           k.append(j)

print(k)
#['M', 'y', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'i', 's', 'A', 'n', 'a', 's', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', 'S', 'c', 'i', 'e', 'n', 't', 'i', 's', 't', 'I', 'a', 'm', 'S', 't', 'u', 'd', 'y', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'S']
```

If you just want:

```
["M","y","N","a","m","e","i","s","A","n","a","s"]
```

you can do:

```
k=[]
for i in dataset[0][0]:
    for j in i:
        if j!=' ':
           k.append(j)

#['M', 'y', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'i', 's', 'A', 'n', 'a', 's']
```

**Edit:**

I think you are looking for this:

```
print([[j for j in i[0] if j!=' '] for i in dataset])

#[['M', 'y', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'i', 's', 'A', 'n', 'a', 's'], ['I', 'a', 'm', 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', 'S', 'c', 'i', 'e', 'n', 't', 'i', 's', 't'], ['I', 'a', 'm', 'S', 't', 'u', 'd', 'y', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'B', 'S', 'C', 'S']]
```

Comment: My data is so big, my terminal almost stops working. But your solution worked Thanks.

GOD BLESS YOU!

Comment: Ameen..and you too brother !

Answer (score 0):

If it is not important for the exercise that you use a nested `for`, then you can simply use one `for` and the fact that a string is already kind of a list.

```py
dataset = [
    ["My name is Anas", 1.92],
    ["I am data Scientist",1.88],
    ["I am Studying BSCS",2.0]
]

for row in dataset:
    print(list(row[0]))
```

if a result that excludes spaces is important, then you can do that like this using the prior answer and a list comprehension to exclude spaces.:

```py
dataset = [
    ["My name is Anas", 1.92],
    ["I am data Scientist",1.88],
    ["I am Studying BSCS",2.0]
]

for row in dataset:
    print([
        character
        for character
        in row[0]
        if character.strip()
    ])
```

If the use of a nested `for` is central to the task, then I would do something like this:

```py
dataset = [
    ["My name is Anas", 1.92],
    ["I am data Scientist",1.88],
    ["I am Studying BSCS",2.0]
]

for row in dataset:
    for column in row:
        if isinstance(column, str):
            print(list(column))
```

Rather than `isinnstace()` you might `enumerate()` and act on only index 0 if you wished.  Again this could be modified with a comprehension to exclude spaces.

Answer (score -1):

I guess something like this, if you don't want the spaces:

```
for row in dataset:
    ...:     string=row[0]
    ...:     print([c for c in string if c != ' '])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
splited = []

for i in dataset:
  for char in i[0]:
    if char != " ":
      splited.append(char)
    else:
      pass
```

Comment: The `else:` part is not needed here

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?